Breadcrumb customization : term_exists returns null when term exists
I am trying to customize the breadcrumb links in a woocommerce installation in the breadcrumbs section. The below code is implemented in functions.php. I check if term exists but I think I miss something in that part.
function custom_breadcrumb( $crumbs, $object_class ){
echo "<!-- DEBUG_crumbs " . print_r($crumbs, true) . "-->";

// Loop through all $crumb
foreach( $crumbs as $key => $crumb ){
    $taxonomy = 'ANIMALS'; // The product category taxonomy
    echo "<!-- DEBUG_crumb0 " . print_r($crumb[0], true) . "-->";
    echo "<!-- DEBUG_taxonomy " . print_r($taxonomy, true) . "-->";

    // Check if it is a product category term
    $term_array = term_exists( $crumb[0], $taxonomy );
    echo "<!-- DEBUG_term_Exists " . print_r($term_array, true) . "-->";
        
    // if it is a product category term
    if ( $term_array !== 0 && $term_array !== null ) {

        // Get the WP_Term instance object
        $term = get_term( $term_array['term_id'], $taxonomy );
        echo "<!-- DEBUG3 " . print_r($term, true) . "-->";
        
        // HERE set your new link with a custom one
        $custom_url = 'https://customurl.com';
        $crumbs[$key][1] = $custom_url ;    
    }   
}
return $crumbs;
}

By checking the console I can see that the term is matching but the result of $term_array is NULL.
<!-- DEBUG_crumb0 ANIMALS-->
<!-- DEBUG_taxonomy ANIMALS-->
<!-- DEBUG_term_Exists-->

In DEBUG_crumbs I can see
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Home
            [1] => https://home.com
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => ANIMALS
            [1] => https://home.com/product-category/animals/
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => SLOHT
            [1] => https://home.com/product/sloht/
        )

)


And what you have in echo "<!-- DEBUG_crumbs " . print_r($crumbs, true) . "-->";  ?

@Snuffy I updated the question with this info. Thank you

$term_array = term_exists( $crumb[0], $taxonomy ); $taxonomy should expect product_cat not animals since this is your taxonomy where animals is a category (term)
